# How to execute eclipse under java VisualVM

Tags: eclipse, visualvm, jvisualvm

I developed couple of plugins specific for my project and I think I have some leackage because my eclipse slow down after long using time, so I want to profile it. I can run eclipse from eclipse (in plugins development mode) and connect it to JVVM, but problem (slow eclipse) occurs after long time of "normal" development, so I want to start my "normal" eclipse and connect to VisualVM.
Problem is that eclipse appears in VisualVM as  and I can't profile it in any way (I see only number of classes loaded, heap and threads).

My JAVA_HOME is set to JDK, I put the same JDK to eclipse.ini under -vm parameter and from the same JDK I am starting VisualVM.

Does someone know what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows? It looks like VisualVM is running under 32bit JDK, while Eclipse is running on 64bit JDK (or vice versa). Check 'Overview' tab when you open Eclipse and VisualVM in VisualVM. This will tell you, which JDK is used.